# Trouble deploying/hosting a node app on heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mongoose, deployment

I am trying to deploy my node js application on Heroku, the application is deployed successfully but when I try to open the app it shows an application error.

The app works totally fine over the localhost. The environment variables are also set and all mongoose models are correctly exported.

The logs are:

```
Starting process with
command `node app.js`
2019-07-15T17:02:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-15T17:02:21.715707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630743+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630764+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630765+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630768+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630770+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './debug'
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630772+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630774+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630776+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630778+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630780+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:14:28)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630782+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630784+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630786+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630788+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.630790+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
2019-07-15T17:02:21.695811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-15T17:02:39.924365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=theindianstore.herokuapp.com
request_id=77c645d3-26e5-4039-a85d-df7ac3807692 fwd="27.63.166.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-15T17:02:41.158705+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=theindianstore.herokuapp.com request_id=938a0f61-5a4c-43b5-b56c-b7cf8c1acbb5 fwd="27.63.166.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make sure all your modules are included. If you have an uncommited file called `debug.js` that's likely the culprit.

Comment: But there is no file that I named **debug.js** and also there's no file left **uncommitted**!

Comment: And the app is also working completely fine on the localhost the error keeps showing on heroku

Comment: If you remove your node modules locally and run npm i, does it still work locally?